# Can comments or brace style break C# code?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I have seen comments breaking Java code, and I remember that brace style could mess with C++ code. Are there any cases in which comments or brace style (or coding style in general) can influence the correctness or source code? I can't think of any off the top of my head.

(I am explicitly not asking how to comment and which brace style to chose, unless it is a direct consequence of trying to keep code correctness.)

Comment: How have you seen comments breaking Java code? Examples would really help here...

Comment: If it does your parser sucks.

Comment: @Jon: `// new Character('\u000d');` (http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue050.html) - pure evil, even though technically it is correct

Comment: I was wondering whether you were thinking about that, but didn't want to suggest it otherwise :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've brought up the "unicode escape sequences in comments" issue (in the comments to the question) - C# is *not* vulnerable to this. Escape sequences such as `\u000d` are *only* converted to corresponding Unicode characters in string and character literals, and in identifiers.

As for the bracing aspect: my guess is that's to do with macros in C++, although again an example would be handy. Not a problem in C#, which doesn't have macros.

There are some subtle issues with other style choices, such as whether your `using` directives appear [inside or outside the namespace declaration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/25/inside-or-outside.aspx). But nothing in terms of comments and braces as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Yep, it was related to macros. Experienced it myself many years ago (still with the VS6 compiler), but I fail to recall any examples.

Answer (score 3):

No, it can't, and more importantly: it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft C# parser: no. The [Mono parser](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) is also fairly stable.